# Convert distance() in shapely to kilometres

Tags: python, distance, shapely

I am using the following code:

```
x = POINT(-1.154321, 55.124412)
y = POINT(-1.2354352, 56.2345235)

distance = x.distance(y)

print(distance)
```

I am unsure what distance measurement is being used, but my distance is returning very small numbers e.g. 0.0.....

Is it possible to return KMs or Miles distance using shapely?

Comment: Shapely do a cartesian distance in the unit of the data. If degree, distance is in degree. See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80881/what-is-unit-of-shapely-length-attribute to solve your issue: knowing why degree, and calculate in meters/kilometers You may also look at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/184340/shapely-distance-different-from-geopy-haversine

Answer (score 3):

To get the distance between two points you could use the [`geometry_length`](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/api/geod.html#pyproj.Geod.geometry_length) function from pyproj. It returns the geodesic length in meters of a given shapely geometry.

```
from pyproj import Geod
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString

line_string = LineString([Point(-1.154321, 55.124412), Point(-1.2354352, 56.2345235)])
geod = Geod(ellps="WGS84")

print(geod.geometry_length(line_string))
'123700.61484174021'
```

That would mean the distance between your two points is about 123.7 km.