# LineString length obtained from shapely differs from actual real distance

Tags: python, distance, shapely, interpolation

I want to obtain the points of a LineString that are at a distance of 25m from the first point and from the last one of said LineString. I was doing some tests to check whether or not Shapely could be used for this task by using `interpolate()` and found a discrepancy between the real segment distance and the distance given by Shapely.

I have a LineString going from `(40.41475479999999, -3.688968499999999)` to `(40.4139832, -3.6889473)`. If I calculate the distance between these two points using `shapely.distance()` the result is `0.000771`, but calculating the distance with any other method, such as `geopy.distance.geodesic().m` returns the real distance, `85.68m`.

The decimals differ, but I would not mind it if Shapely returned something like `0.000857`, I would just need to remove the 0s to get the actual value.

Why is Shapely giving a completely different value? I'll leave some code below for anyone wanting to check for themselves.

```
import geopy.distance
import shapely

dist1 = shapely.distance(shapely.Point((40.41475479999999, -3.688968499999999)), shapely.Point((40.4139832, -3.6889473)))


dist2 = geopy.distance.geodesic((40.41475479999999, -3.688968499999999), (40.4139832, -3.6889473)).m

print("Shapely distance: {} - Geodesic distance: {}".format(dist1, dist2))
```

Comment: `Shapely.distance()` returns the cartesian distance in degrees in this case which is pretty much useless. you might want to check out https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/403637/convert-distance-in-shapely-to-kilometres